# How to setup telnet to accept remote connections

Tags: server, remote, telnet

I am using Ubuntu server 13.10 and I am trying to get my telnet to work. I am using a vpn service to test the remote connection.
Connection:

```
MBMacBook-Pro:~ mb: telnet telnet.mysite.com 666
Trying IP...
telnet: connect to address IP: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

But when I try it on my local network, it works. How can I get the telnet service to work for remote connections?

Answer (score 2):

A firewall may be blocking your connection.

There can be two cases:

- Firewall on the server is blocking incoming access to port 666. (This may include             firewall on the server and an additional layer of firewall if you are using a cloud service     like Amazon EC2)
- Firewall on your client machine may be blocking outgoing access to port 666.

In any case you need to add an exception to port 666 in the relevant machines.

Comment: The firewall on the server is just fine and the client machine isn't either I've already tried my routers any other tips

Comment: Can you ping the host from the remote machine?


$ ping telnet.mysite.com

Comment: yes I can! But on the computer I am trying to connect from uses vpnbook it can ping but not connect if that is of any help at all

Comment: If it is not a security issue try to: 1. temporary disable the firewall using $ sudo ufw disabled 

2. Try using the IP address directly in telnet command, $telnet ServerIP 666 

3. If you can access the server without VPN try to do the above operation outside the VPN.

Comment: I have already tried that it still failed the canyouseeme.org did work for ports 20-30 that I have all opened for the telnet operations

Comment: ok I have no clue whats going on but it seems it was blocking my vpn's ip